# prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(a_n)$ converges

Tags: real-analysis

> let $f$ be differentiable on $x=0$.  $f(0)=0, f'(0) \neq 0$
>
> $a_n$ is a positive sequence converging to $0$.
>
> prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges iff $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}f(a_n)$ converges.

I was thinking we know that $f$ has the same sign on $(0, \delta)$ for some $\delta>0$, assuming it is positive for example we can try showing its partial sum sequence is bounded, or other stuff that works for a sequence with the same sign, but with no success  so far.

I'm looking for a **tiny** hint, just for the direction assuming $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ converges

Comment: Hint: first-order Taylor expansion. $f(x) = f(0)+f'(0)x + o(x)$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you said you only wanted a **tiny** hint.

**HINT.** Use the definition of the derivative at $x=0$.

Perhaps a stronger hint, '*use*' the Mean Value Theorem. [Note it does not apply here. But if it did, what would you use it to do?  You will observe that the same things you use the MVT to produce can be obtained from the definition of the derivative alone in this case. Except I think it is simpler to see what you want in the MVT case before trying to deal with the limit definition of the derivative case.]

Comment: the first hint was all i needed, brilliant :)

Comment: @numbdigger I think Clement C.'s comment actually produces the same result end result I was looking for much more easily than my hint gets you there, so I wish he had posted it as an answer! But thank you all the same.

Comment: actually he is wrong imo, we only know f is differentiable on one point. don't we need an interval for taylor?

Comment: @numbdigger I believe you are correct, and was the same issue I thought about when I saw the comment. But I never use the theorem so it's something I always have to look up to remember the exact conditions. In any case, it's essentially the same 'bad' thing as MVT in what it tries to produce but I think it's cleaner than the 'false' MVT hint. I'm just glad the derivative definition was enough to see the method.

Answer (score 2):

As you already pointed out, $f$ keeps the same sign in a small interval $I=(0, \delta)$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $f|_I>0$.

Assuming the series $\sum a_n$ converges, first note that $a_n \to 0$. Therefore there exists $N>0$ such that for all $n>N$, $f(a_n) \le c \times a_n $ where $c>0$ can be chosen independently of $n$. Let us prove that this is indeed the case.

> **Hint**: By the differentiability of $f$ at $0$ we have $0<f'(0) = \lim_n\frac{f(a_n)- f(0)}{a_n}$
>    (**why?**). Hence there exists $N_1>0$ such that for
>   all $n>N_1$ we have $\frac{f(a_n)- f(0)}{a_n}<2f'(0)$. Rearrange the
>   terms, remember that $f(0)=0$ and conclude.

I hope this helps. If you have any further question/remark, feel free to ask.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you may prove both directions simultaneously.

If we assume, without loss of generality, that $f'(0) > 0$, then there exist $0 < \alpha < \beta$ such that $\alpha x \leq f(x) \leq \beta x$ for sufficiently small (positive) $x$.

Is this enough for a hint?